# Laravel passport after deployment

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2, laravel-passport, bearer-token

I run a laravel App on a aws ec2 instance and use laravel passport to secure my api with Bearer tokens.

After each deployment the passport keys are gone so i added a passport:install command after every deployment.

This forces all users to Relogin.

There musst be a better solution to handle this behavior.

How can i handle a deployment without the passport:install command and without forcing all users to relogin?

A solution or a bester way

Comment: When you say deployment, do you mean git pull updated code?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to run `passport:install` after your initial deployment.

The Passport keys are installed by default in `storage/oauth-public.key` and `storage/oauth-private.key`. You'll need to update your deployment script so that these files are not removed.

For a more specific answer, you'll need to add more details about your deployment method.

Comment: Hey, thx for your help. 

On our deployment we complete destroy the ec2 instances and create a new one. 
So i pull the complete repo on the new ec2 instance. 

Can i save the keys to my env?

Comment: @Laravelbeginner99 How do you recreate your `.env` file? It's not in the repo, is it?